# FFmpeg - How to replace the image of a video with a png without modifying the audio?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm trying to modify several videos as quickly as possible. The goal is to replace the original image of the videos with a black or white image, in short, an image with nothing.

Searching the internet I found two lines of code (both work):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i x.png -i "y.mp4" -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset slow -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4

ffmpeg -i x.png -i "y.mp4" -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][v];[v][i]overlay" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

but which one to use? or rather what is the fastest way to do this without audio loss? Loss of video quality is not a problem as long as the minimum resolution is 426x240.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modified version of the first command after resizing the image using a second command.

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i resized.png -i "y.mp4" -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4`

Resize image:

`ffmpeg -i x.png -vf scale=426:240,setsar=1 resized.png`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Gyan's answer:
Copy all video files and the "resized.png" image to the same directory and run a "FOR loop" from the command line inside that directory.

UNIX/LINUX systems:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -loop 1 -i resized.png -i "$f" -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a copy -shortest "${f%.mp4}_OUT.mp4"; done
```

I don't use windows but it should be something like this:

```
for %f in (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -loop 1 -i resized.png -i "%f" -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a copy -shortest "%~nf_OUT.mp4"
```

All the video files should be processed sequentially.